# Did Rav Dovid Leibowitz write any chiddushei Torah?

Tags: history, torah-writing, jewish-american-history

[Rav Dovid Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovid_Leibowitz?wprov=sfla1) was a talmid of the Chafetz Chaim and the father of [Rav Henoch Leibowitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henoch_Leibowitz?wprov=sfla1). I have heard in the name of Rav Yitzchak Hutner that out of all the yeshivas in America, only Rav Leibowitz's yeshiva attempted to create a "mussar yeshiva" in the same style as the European mussar Yeshivas, I.e. A yeshiva that put an emphasis on personal growth and not only learning Torah per se.

My question is, do we possess any material written by Rav Leibowitz?

Comment: See book tiferes dovid in general, and the appendix contains letters of divrey torah between him and Avraham Eliya Kaplan, maybe others too

Comment: His sudden death may have been a contributing factor to any dearth

Comment: That quote from Rav Hutner is hard to believe, as Rabbi Ruderman intended Ner Yisroel to be a continuation of the Slabodka tradition.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Do you know where I can purchase the sefer Tiferes Dovid?

Comment: @Gavriel looks like it's recently Back in print! https://zbermanbooks.com/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94 I assume that's the right one otherwise it's behind a paywall on otzar hachochmah

Comment: Disclaimer I don't recall but I don't think they were ethical writings per SE can get into it right now